# Is "tennis" an adjective in "tennis coach"?

Tags: adjectives

Is "tennis" an adjective in "tennis coach"? My english teacher thinks so, but using my native language as a reference it doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: No, it's a noun. It's function is complement to the noun "coach".

Comment: When your English teacher says so, just believe what he says is right. Your question seems to be too basic for this community. For future questions, I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @BillJ ~ in what way is 'tennis' a complement? It is not an argument of anything, and "he is my coach" is as complete as "he is my tennis coach" which makes "tennis" an adjunct: "In grammar, a noun adjunct or attributive noun or noun (pre)modifier is an optional noun that modifies another noun" (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct#/search)

Comment: This topic has been transferred to a new question.

Comment: This is a religious issue.  Some folks are of the religion that "tennis", in the above context, becomes an adjective, while others assign one of several other categories to it.  But all this is just playing with words, which is, not too oddly, something that many in the linguistics community love to do.  In this case, as in many, the answer you get will depend on which book your "authority" read last, in his attempt to apply mathematical rigor to something which is inherently "squishy".

Answer (score 1):

It is a ***[noun adjunct](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/noun_adjunct)***:

> - a noun that modifies another noun and that is optional (that is, it can be removed without affecting the grammar of the sentence).
>   For example, in the compound noun "chicken soup", the noun adjunct "chicken" modifies the noun "soup".

(Wiktionary)

Comment: I agree that it's a noun, but it's not a modifier; it's a complement.

Comment: Downvote for answering this.

Comment: +1 for being correct. It is indeed a noun adjunct, AKA an attributive noun.

Comment: That's funny, because it doesn't obey the coordination rules for adjuncts. A coach on tennis and vaccation?